# How to asynchronously await an Akka.Actor event?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, event-handling, akka, akka.net

I am using akka.NET. In most cases we use akka like this:

```cs
class ActorA : UntypedActor
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object arg1, object arg2, ...);
    public static event EventHandler Event;
}
actorA.Event += some_function;
```

In this case we execute `some_function(arg1, arg2)` whenever `Event.Invoke(arg1, arg2)` is called. Now assume that we have an asynchrounous HTTP server, and I am trying to let the server asynchronously await `actorA.Event` to happen, after a client calls the server. I do not need to run `some_function` when `Event` happens, but I have to ensure that the runtime context is switched back into the functions of the HTTP server. That is:

```cs
// in the methods of the HTTP server...
public async void AwaitAnEvent()
{
    await ReturnOnEvent(actorA.Event);
}
```

Is it possible to efficiently implement `ReturnOnEvent` which returns immediately when the next `actorA.Event.Invoke(arg1, arg2)` is called?

Comment: Akka's actors shall communicate with other actors through messages. For other cases, I would recommend reading this article.

https://petabridge.com/blog/async-await-vs-pipeto/

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question - is the `EventHandler` being called from outside the actor? Why not just send a message to the actor via `IActorRef.Tell`?

Comment: @Aaronontheweb I have edited the question supplying more details. `Tell` seems to provide no way for me to switch to the context of another method

Answer (score 0):

This case smells a bit.
inside the web controller just ask your actor and that will trigger it to generate response.

When asking it will await in the controller to get response.

```
var response =  myActor.Ask<ResponseType>(new GiveMySomeFoodMsg());
-- in the actor
Sender.Tell(new ResponseType(some data here))
```

Comment: Then we additionally need the actor to efficiently await another sender asking a message, before telling the original sender

Comment: ask is async by default - pls check the signature